# ScopeConfig is not working in 'checkout_cart_update_items_after' observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I use an observer `checkout_cart_update_items_after` to update the price of a product.In Vendor\Module\Observer\PriceRule\UpdateObserver my observer code resides.In this class I need to use ScopeConfigInterface. But when I declare it in the constructor like this--

```
 public function __construct(
    Session $session,

    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
) {
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
```

My observer stop working.But when I remove this two line--

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
$this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
```

it works fine.But I need to use scope config to implement my logic.
Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clear contents of `generated/code`, or if you have compilation enabled, either disable it by removing the contents of `generated/metadata` or compile again with `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to flush the cache, if still not work then just remove "var/generation" and it will work

```
public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
{
  $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
  $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
  return parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Oh, i got it, you miss this in your contruct, see below

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory
    ...
) {
```

Comment: ok I am trying this .

Comment: Hi @john,It is not working.

Comment: see my updated answer